# Mysql query string too long

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-20.04

I'm experiencing a strange mysql behaviour that occurs between two virtual machines.

When I have a query string longer than 1457 chars, the connection I'm using hangs.
I was thinking the problem was a query with a tons of result but then discovered that
the query string is not important.

For example:

```
select * from users where uname = "abcdefffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffpooooooooooppppppppfooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooffffffseroieeeeuuwwwwwwwwwwwuii";
```

hangs the server.

If i remove a single char from that string, mysql returns an empty recordset, as expected. There is not a such user and the field uname is varchar(64). The table, contains just one record.

I tried to monitor the socket and discovered that the querystring is retransmitted 20 times and then the traffic stops but the client does not exit and connection is not dropped/closed.cd

```
192.168.0.111:43012 -> 192.168.0.112:mysql
    ...
    bytes_sent:22614
    bytes_retrans:20260
    bytes_acked:329
    bytes_received:8208
    segs_out:28
    segs_in:10
    data_segs_out:18
    data_segs_in:8
    ...
```

The very same query made from a different instance to the same server, works flawlessy.
I tried the official mysql terminal client, an alternative terminal client and a script but I got the same result.

Comment: File a bug report with a concrete example at bugs.mysql.com

Comment: This could be an issue with MTU setting on the network interfaces on the host. Might be that the query ends up in a too long TCP segment, which is then dropped by the kernel.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @RickJames. It is difficult to file a bug report. The problem is limited to a single server vm when it interacts with a specific vm client. I replicated the two vms and the problem gone away. I Rebooted the two original vms and the problem persists. If just one of the two machines change, the problem will not occurs.

Comment: @Eineki - Thanks for trying.  "client" -- mysql commandline client?  Or something else?

Comment: Yes, @RickJames mysql command line client, mycli, an alternative commandline client written in python and a very simple php script (connect, send the query, retrieve the empty recordset and close connection) written on purpose. Same result. I'm starting to think of the mtu as #TeroKilkanen pointed out (the string lenght should have set that bell ringing).